# How can i click element in this map by using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

https://largelots.org/#/browse?pin=16133260140000

I've written a script in python with selenium to scrape different data lie within different parcels on a map. Each data is connected to each parcel. The data is activated once either of the parcels are clicked.

i wrote the code but it doesn't work

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/bigdata/Python/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://largelots.org/#/browse?pin=16054180290000")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="map"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[2]').click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
token = parse_qs(urlparse(frame.get_attribute("src")).query)

driver.close()
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i did not update my script because i guess my code is totally wrong. i heard that if i want to extract some data from the map i don't have to click all the point.